# Removing lower case letter in column of Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df

```
data = {'Name':['TOMy', 'NICKs', 'KRISHqws', 'JACKdpo'], 'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18]}
```

How can I remove lowercase letters from the Name column such that when looking at `data['Name']`, I have `TOM,NICK,KRISH,JACK`.

I tried the following but no luck,

```
data['Name'].mask(data['Name'].str.match(r'^[a-z]+$'))
data['Name'] = data['Name'].str.translate(None,string.ascii_lowercase)
```

Comment: df.Name.str.replace(r'[a-z]+','') ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update the `name` column by making use of [**`.str.replace(..)`** [pandas-doc]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace('[a-z]', '')
```

For the given sample data, this gives us:

```
>>> df['Name'].str.replace('[a-z]', '')
0      TOM
1     NICK
2    KRISH
3     JACK
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this too if you don't like RegEx:

```
df['Name'].apply(lambda x: ''.join([letter for letter in x if letter.isupper()]))
```

*For all rows in the `Name` column, concatenate all letters that are uppercase.*